# Changing each word in the sentence on asterisk

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want each word in the sentence to be changed on asterisk, I'm trying to use one line code here, but I have no idea how do I get the asterisk for *each* word

```
from string import join, split
def asterisk(s):
        return  join(map(lambda x: x[:0], split(s)), " * ")

print asterisk("lame af sentence")
```

The output:

```
 *  *
```

As you could notice it changes only 2 words after `split()`. I have tried to use *lambda function* to assign `x = " * "` to the asterisk, but it doesn't support that way.

So, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: these days people prefer to use the methods of the `str` object, not the functions in the `string` module, which have been removed from Python 3.  IOW, we'd typically write `somestr.split()`, not `from string import split` and then `split(somestr)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code puts an asterisk between every join. There are 2 join between words, so two asterisks.

I think you want

```
 join(map(lambda x: "*", split(s)), " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split` and `str.join` here:

```
>>> strs = "lame af sentence"
>>> ' '.join('*'*len(strs.split()))
'* * *'
```

Here `str.split` splits the string at white-spaces and returns a list:

```
>>> spl = strs.split()
>>> spl
['lame', 'af', 'sentence']
```

Now using the length of this list and `str.join` we can do:

```
>>> ' '.join("*"*len(spl))
'* * *'
```

---

If you want to preserve the white-spaces, regex may help:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "lame af        sentence"
>>> re.sub(r'\S+', '*', strs)
'* *        *'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one you could use:

```
def asterisk(s):
    return ' '.join(['*' for word in s.split()])

print asterisk("lame af sentence")
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. **Count how many words you have:** `words=len(s.split())`
2. **Add one `*` followed by a space per word:** `for i in range(words): out+='* '`
3. **Cut last space:** `out=out[:-1]`

In one line: `return '* '.join([i for i in range(len(s.split()))])[:-1]`